# Debugger does not start, but working fine start without debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2017

I am a bit stuck with my project in c#, .net 4.5.2, using VS2017 debugger does not start, when debugging but starts when start without debugging is selected.

Also, application does not work (unable to login) in start without debugging.

Things I have tried:

1. Clean, Rebuild, Restart solution
2. Updated with new version (thought it was error for old version)
3. Check with break point and log for loading vs symbol servers

Still not working.

Comment: So your application doesn't run when you `start with debugging`, yet it does run when you `start without debugging` ?

Comment: Right. Shows unable to connect in browser but debugging process keeps on running.

Comment: Sounds like you might have set a breakpoint in the site's startup code. BTW is it a site? You should tag `ASP.NET` or whatever tech you're using.

Comment: Does firewall blocks debugging of code?

Comment: If you want to eliminate the firewall as a possible issue, check your [IIS W3C logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/provisioning-and-managing-iis/configure-logging-in-iis). If you see traffic, the issue isn't the F/W.

Comment: Issue was solved, In project properties->web->debuggers, native debugger was checked. After unchecking that and building the project, the application was able to debug, hitting the break points. Thanks btw.

Comment: @Manoj Glad to hear that, you could post your solution and mark it as answer to help more people.Thanks!

Comment: Sure. Will you help me with this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49464030/gdi-error-saving-files-to-clients-temp-folder
Dynamically created images in Temp folder of server(remote) gets excluded from project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was solved, 
In `project` `properties->web->debuggers`, `native` debugger was checked. After `unchecking` that and building the project, the application was able to `debug`, hitting the `break points`.